# Perform pivot operation on the table but facing problem as it requires multiple aggregate function to segregate dates into two columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot

I have this table named hotel which contains EmpId and their corresponding [check-in/out] column in datetime format.

[image: The table looks like this]

Now, I want the data in table to look like this.

[image: Desired table]

I have tried following simple query and it's working correctly:

```
select EmpId, min([Check-in/out]) as Checkin, max([Check-in/out]) as Checkout 
from [dbo].[hotel]
group by EmpId;
```

But i want to do it using pivot operator in sql server. I have tried the following query but it's incorrect:

```
select EmpId, Min([Check-in/out]) AS Checkin, Max([Check-in/out]) AS Checkout  
FROM  
(select EmpId, [Check-in/out] from [dbo].[hotel]) AS SourceTable  
PIVOT  
(  
min([Check-in/out])   
FOR [Check-in/out] IN(Checkin)  
)AS PivotTable1
PIVOT
(  
max([Check-in/out])   
FOR [Check-in/out] IN(Checkout)  
)AS PivotTable2;
```

Comment: In your data, what tells you that a row is a check in or out? Nothing defines them. What if a user has 3 entries in a day? What about 4, or 12?

Comment: Why do you want to use `PIVOT` where with the simplistic design you have, `MIN` and `MAX` are definitely the correct choice.

Comment: I suggest using cte / subqueries in order to approach this problem... first of all, select EmpID, time and rownumber (partition by empid and order by time) - this gives you all checkins with odd rownumber and all checkouts with even rownumber. Next - basing on this query - select empid, time and `CASE WHEN rownumber%2=0 THEN 'CHECKOUT' ELSE 'CHECKIN' END AS CheckInOut`... this result again can be used in your pivot statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here again my comment as answer with an example:

I suggest using cte / subqueries in order to approach this problem... first of all, select EmpID, time and rownumber (partition by empid and order by time) - this gives you all checkins with odd rownumber and all checkouts with even rownumber. Next - basing on this query - select empid, time and CASE WHEN rownumber%2=0 THEN 'CHECKOUT' ELSE 'CHECKIN' END AS CheckInOut... this result again can be used in your pivot statement

Example:

```
WITH cte AS(
SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY EmpID ORDER BY CheckInOut) rn
  FROM T1
),
cteInOut AS(
SELECT EmpID, CheckInOut, CASE WHEN rn%2 = 0 THEN N'CheckOut' ELSE N'CheckIn' END AS CheckInOutState
  FROM cte
),
cteInOuntSrt AS(
  SELECT EmpID, CheckInOut, CheckInOutState, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY EmpID, CheckInOutState ORDER BY CheckInOut) rn1
    FROM cteInOut
)
select EmpID, rn1 AS CheckIndIdx, CheckIn, CheckOut
from cteInOuntSrt
pivot
(
  min(CheckInOut)
  for CheckInOutState in ([CheckIn], [CheckOut])
) piv
ORDER BY 1, 2;
```

fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/af6f3/1/1

Answer (score 0):

If the values line up, you can use `lead()` and `row_number()`:

```
select c.empid, checkin, checkout
from (select c.*, [Check-in/out] as checkin,
             lead([Check-in/out]) over (partition by empid order by [Check-in/out]) as checkout,
             row_number() over (partition by empid order by [Check-in/out]) as seqnum
      from [Check-in/out] c
     ) c
where seqnum % 2 = 1;
```

This does the following calculations:

- Calculate the next date/time value.
- Enumerate the rows, starting the count from 1.
- Taking the odd-numbered rows.  These are the check ins.